# Python - nested lists q

Tags: python-3.x

Pasted my code below. I'm trying to isolate the "name" value of a list inside the nested list the api replies with but its not detected as a nested list for some reason. My response or what the decode variable prints is:

```
[{"id":"a981fdae11a949b2bb3c78cc2c7f820d","name":"Juice"},{"id":"ec07182556b444d38e9af48bf74bde82","name":"Dog"},{"id":"2aca11f3fa364adf83183e10e8794c46","name":"csheim","legacy":true}]
```

From the above output I need to isolate / print the name "csheim" as its sub list contains "legacy : true" but as I said above, I get this when even try to detect sub/nested lists inside my list so I don't know how to go about this. Error:     print(decode[1][1])
IndexError: string index out of range

```
import requests
import time
import socket
import json
import string

host_ip = socket.gethostname()

print("")
print(socket.gethostbyname(host_ip))
print("")
time.sleep(2)


payload = ["juice", "csheim", "dog"]
r = requests.post('https://api.example.com', json=payload)


decode = r.text
print(decode)
print(decode[1][1])
```

Comment: what do you get when you use ```print(decode)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse it with json library , then treat that like an array of dictionaries.
Try this :

```
import requests
import time
import socket
import json
import string

host_ip = socket.gethostname()

print("")
print(socket.gethostbyname(host_ip))
print("")
time.sleep(2)


payload = ["juice", "csheim", "dog"]
r = requests.post('https://api.example.com', json=payload)

decode = json.loads(r.text)

for item in decode :
    if "legacy" in item :
        print(item["name"])
```